# Using NSPredicate to match against a list of integers

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a table with an integer field. I want to select all rows where that field contains any of a few different values.

I'm using this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myIntValue IN {1,2,3,4}"]
```

but this only returns rows where `myIntValue` is 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSArray *idList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                                            nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idealForId IN $IDLIST"];
request.predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:idList forKey:@"IDLIST"]];
```

Comment: Core Data only stores objects so you always have to convert scalars to objects when you create predicates.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myIntValue IN %@",
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil]];
```

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-250409) may be of use here.

Comment: I believe that may work for strings, but it doesn't seem to work for integers. I tried [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] instead of @"1", but that didn't work either.

Comment: @"1" is a NSString, @1 is an NSNumber

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this has changed since the question was originally posted but I get the exact same predicate from all three of these.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myIntValue IN {1, 2, 3, 4}"];

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myIntValue IN {%d, %d, %d, %d}", 1, 2, 3, 4];

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myIntValue IN %@", @[@1, @2, @3, @4]];
```

So no need to wrap everything in objects.